How To Solve "ERROR: Could not build wheels for mathutils" in Python 3.9.6
I'm trying to install ifcopenshell on python. I get this error:
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mathutils
  Running setup.py clean for mathutils
Failed to build mathutils
ERROR: Could not build wheels for mathutils, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I tried
python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

but did not work. First, it was the "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required error" so I downloaded Build Tools with Desktop development with C++. After that it gives the "Failed building wheel for mathutils" error.
How can I solve this?
